# Conditions under which the degree of an algebraic surface equals the degree of its planar section

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, reference-request

An algebraic surface $\Phi$ in complex projective 3-space contains a circle $c$ such that the complex projective plane $P$ of $c$ intersects $\Phi$ only at the points of $c$. Assume that

- $c$ is not a singular curve of $\Phi$;
- $P$ does not touch $\Phi$ along the curve $c$.

Is it true that then $\Phi$ is a quadric? What is a good reference for that?

Comment: I guess that by "circle" you mean a non-singular conic.
Then the result follows from a straightforward application of Bezout's theorem in $\mathbf{P}^3$. For a reference, see Shafarevich's book *Basic Algebraic Geometry 1*, p. 236-237.

Comment: Thanks! Of course that's Bezout but I was not sure if any condition was forgotten